# Vuex get for loop id to axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

i have a problem about getting the id from for loop then insert it into axios. i will give you a sample.

Heres my code

```
<ul v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <li><h1>{{ post.name}} </h1></li>
      <slide v-for="(lesson, index) in lesson1" :key="index">
        <img :src="lesson.image_url">
      </slide>
    </li>
</ul>

 computed: {
    ...mapState('Gallery', ['posts',
                            'lesson1',
                            ]), 
      },
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('Gallery/loadPosts');
    this.$store.dispatch('Gallery/loadLesson1',[1]);
}
```

Then in my VUEX

```
state: {
        posts: [],
        lesson1: [],
   },
mutations: {
    SET_POSTS(state, data) {
        state.posts = data;
    },
    LOAD_1(state, data) {
        state.lesson1 = data;
    }
  },

   actions: {
    loadPosts(ctx) {

        axios
            .get('/api/posts/', {

            })
            .then(res => {
                ctx.commit('SET_POSTS', res.data)
            })
     },
     loadLesson1(ctx, imgId) {

        axios.get('api/post/lesson/'+imgId, { 
        })
        .then(res => {
          var datas = res.data;
            ctx.commit('LOAD_1', datas)
        })
    },
```

i want to get the id in for loop then store it in lesson then it will get the data of lesson base on id post. for example i have 10 posts then i will get the 10 ids of post then display the lessons base on post ids. please help Thanks in Advance

Example Output:

```
   post 1
     img1, img2, img3,  img4, img5
   post 2
     img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12
   post 3,
     img13, img14, img15
   post 4,
     img16
   post 5,
     img17, img18, img19, img20
```

Its like netflix gallery

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> It's *recommended* doing the `mapping` on the basis of `id` in a **`getter / computed`**
>   itself ie. before rendering the data in the `<template>`

```
// vuex
getters: {
 getPosts: state => {
  return state.posts.map(post => {
   let lesson = state.lesson1.find(lesson => lesson.id == post.id)
   return { ...lesson, ...post }
  })
 }
}

// template
<ul v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
 <li>
  <h1>{{ post.name}}</h1>
  <slide><img :src="post.image_url"></slide>
 </li>
</ul>

// script
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getPosts']) // After mapping the getter, you can use `getPosts` in your template
 }
}
```

**Alternative**: you can use **`v-if`** directive to avoid `rendering` the element if `id` does not match.

```
// template
<ul v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
 <li>
  <h1>{{ post.name}} </h1>
  <template v-for="(lesson, index) in lesson1" :key="index" class="parent">
   <slide v-if="post.id == lesson.id" class="child"> <-- here
    <img :src="lesson.image_url">
   </slide>
  </template>
 </li>
</ul>
```

***Note***: Vue won't let you put both `v-for` & `v-if` on the same element so have wrapped `<slide>` with a `<div>`

Comment: hi v-if is working but the gallery is design will not work. i will try your getters. i hope it will work. thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, [1] pls clarify what do you mean by: gallery is design will not work ?

Comment: i tried v-if before. but the design of gallery was vertical. it should be horizontal. i will be using getters that you said. i will still using this.$store.dispatch('Gallery/loadLesson1',[1]);?

Comment: Hi please help me complete code for your getters. thanks

Comment: you can change the design of the gallery back to horizontal with CSS / flex-box, attaching an example for the same: https://jsbin.com/banebukohe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: you will have to map the getter to use it in your template, everything else with remain same, have updated the answer. Also have updated the alternative approach to keeping the gallery horizontal by CSS.

Comment: @PolCarlo Or if you don't want to put the additional class to keep gallery horizontal, use `template` tag ie. `<template v-for="...>` in place of `<div v-for="...>` have updated the alternative approach as per this. To take the CSS approach, you can still refer to above-mentioned bin link in the comment.

Comment: Hi the post title is working but the image is not showing like the example output. just a 1 blank image

Comment: in loadLesson1(ctx, courseId) {} how can i get the post.id and put it here in courseId?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210111/discussion-between-pol-carlo-and-shivam-singh).